# Puzzled about PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, java

I modified PATH in my ~/.bashrc file
The last two lines of are:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16"
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/javac:$PATH
```

I opened a new terminal and gave some commands, the results are:

```
user@user-Vostro-3669:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/javac:/disk2/BACKUP_OLD_MACHINE/NEW4_mnt_newdisk_VC/NEW4/JAVA_JDK/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/home/user/ROJA_LAKSHMI/BABITA/TERMSUITE/cmd:/home/user/ROJA_LAKSHMI/BABITA/TERMSUITE/bin:/home/user/ROJA_LAKSHMI/BEDREST/HPSG_ACE_ERG/ace-0.9.31/:/home/user/PROGRAMMING_STYLES/EXPERT_SYSTEM/clips_core_source_630/core:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/HASKELL/GHC_8.6.4/ghc-8.6.4/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

user@user-Vostro-3669:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16

user@user-Vostro-3669:~$ which java
/disk2/BACKUP_OLD_MACHINE/NEW4_mnt_newdisk_VC/NEW4/JAVA_JDK/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java

user@user-Vostro-3669:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

user@user-Vostro-3669:~$ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/java -version

java version "16" 2021-03-16

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing
```

My puzzle why am I not getting expected result?

I expected to see:

```
java version "16" 2021-03-16
```

when I gave the command:

```
java -version
```

What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `$PATH` variable lists the order in which *directories* are searched for executable files, not the *files* themselves. Therefore:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/javac:$PATH
```

should be changed to:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatted for convenience...

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16/bin/javac:/disk2/BACKUP_OLD_MACHINE/NEW4_mnt_newdisk_VC/NEW4/JAVA_JDK/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/home/user/ROJA_LAKSHMI/BABITA/TERMSUITE/cmd:/home/user/ROJA_LAKSHMI/BABITA/TERMSUITE/bin:/home/user/ROJA_LAKSHMI/BEDREST/HPSG_ACE_ERG/ace-0.9.31/:/home/user/PROGRAMMING_STYLES/EXPERT_SYSTEM/clips_core_source_630/core:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/HASKELL/GHC_8.6.4/ghc-8.6.4/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`PATH` defines the location and order where to look for executables.

From your example, `/disk2/BACKUP_OLD_MACHINE/NEW4_mnt_newdisk_VC/NEW4/JAVA_JDK/jdk1.8.0_25/bin` is the latest (updated) location where `java` executable was found, and it is the one being used.

`JAVA_HOME` is just another variable, but this one doesn't tell the shell where to look for `java` (`PATH` does that), it's used by various applications.

I'd advise to sort out your `PATH` variable (maybe ditch backup stuff from there). As concerned to applications running Java, most of them (the ones developed in a proper manner) refer to `JAVA_HOME`. Meaning they will use `java` indicated by `JAVA_HOME`, while you running `java` from shell will be redirected to last location indicated by `PATH`.

Might seem a bit confusing, and even worse when you'll want to manually debug anything `java`-related from shell.